# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis, axis2c

While running the application I was getting the following errors.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService`

AxisService class is in `axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar` file. Some of the classes from this jar are working fine without any issues, but some classes are throwing  NoClassDefFoundError from this jar file at runtime. `AxisService`  class is present in `axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar`, even it throws error.

This is working fine in local machine. But error getting in Oracle r12 server.I have already set the class path for the jar file.

**I am Using Java version is 1.6 and Apache axis2.1.6.2.**

Comment: it means that your class is present but method that you are using is not present.

Comment: I have also this issue..but not got a solution for this issue...

Comment: Does you server container have any axis version under lib folder? Are you sure that your application is packaged with axis2-kernel?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti:- yes ,the methods are there in the package.While at run time the class files are not loading.We have tried with eclipse,it works fine...

Comment: @jspboix: Yes. Application is packaged with axis2-kernel.

Comment: @log_in Can you answer the first question? As it could cause a conflict if the container is loading axis2-kernel jar to the classpath from a lib folder while your application tries to do the same.

Comment: @jspboix: No, For this oracle application ,we used to put the jar file in JAVA_TOP and and putting the path for the same.

Comment: For me it smells like some build procedure not behaving as expected but I can't really tell without looking into the ant script or the pom.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. I had included only jars that I needed to compile the application.
When I included everything from \axis2-1.6.2\lib\ folder, this exception were gone.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using Tomcat and Axis2 and after a week finding out the error I realized there was a axis configuration problem. especifically my aplication can't instantiate the class which accedded to persistence layer. I include this parameter line:

```
<parameter name="ServiceTCCL">composite</parameter>
```

in services.xml file which is used by axis2 to work.

For more information see the comments in http://wso2.com/node/1131